# im getting a "NaN" when i use the reduce method on such array of objecs

Tags: javascript

so i want to get the average "Rating" of an array full of student objects (name , age , Rating ....etc) so i used the reduce method to calculate that... which is like :

```js
var std = [
  {
      name : 'david',
      Rating:'8',
      age:'10'  
  },
  {
      name : 'tomas',
      Rating:'5',
      age:'10'
  },
  {
      name : 'raul',
      Rating:'2',
      age:'10'
  }
]
var averageRating = std.reduce(
  (acc,val) => {
      Number(acc.Rating) + Number(val.Rating)) / std.length
  }
)
console.log(averageRating); // output NaN
```

Comment: well what is the starting value in reduce? You missed an argument

Comment: change `.length)` to `.length, 0)`

Comment: Still has issues because you are saying `acc.Rating` but you are returning a number....

Comment: same thing i tried taht

Comment: So how does a number have a property Rating?  console.log(acc, acc.Rating) if acc is `0` than what is 0.rating?

Comment: Also note that you don't want to divide by `std.length` in the `reduce` function. You should reduce to the sum and then divide that sum by `std.length`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem with your code was that if you do not supply initial value, then `acc` takes the first value and `val` takes the second value.

In this case, for first iteration, first 2 items from array are taken and value is calculated which happens to be a number. For second iteration, `acc` is no longer an object and hence, the calculations will fail.

Try following

- Give initial value `0` to reduce function
- Update reduce function to only calculate sum and then divide the result by length of array

```js
var std = [{name: 'david',Rating: '8',age: '10'}, {name: 'tomas',Rating: '5',age: '10'}, {name: 'raul',Rating: '2',age: '10'}];

let avg = std.reduce((a,c) => a + Number(c.Rating), 0)/std.length;
console.log(avg);
```

Comment: @SirDad - Added explanation. Please check

Comment: @SirDad - Glad to help you!

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

Add `0` as an argument to `.reduce`, to provide an initial value for `acc`

### Reason

You didn't provide an initial value, as a second parameter to `.reduce`

If no initial value is provided, then `.reduce` will use the first item of the array, and start running the functions from the second one.

Right now, the first iteration is running `object/number`, which is `NaN`, then the `acc` will be `NaN`, so the next iteration will do `NaN/number`, which is still `NaN` and so forth, until the last value will actually be `NaN`

For more info on how to use `.reduce`, look at the mdn page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

### General problem example

```
const array = ["hi", "there", "what's", "up"];
const charCount = array.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val.length);
```

Here, `charCount` will actually be `"hi562"`

What happened is that the first `acc` was set to `"hi"`, to which was added `"there".length` and so on.

To fix it, you can do this:

```
const array = ["hi", "there", "what's", "up"];
const charCount = array.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val.length, 0);
```

Here, `charCount` is correctly `15`, as initially, `acc=0`, to which a number is added, and so on

### Additional notes

This is actually not your only problem, but it's easy for you to figure out the rest of them from here. Mainly, you don't want `acc.Rating`, but simply `acc`